# How to completely exit the program created by Kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

To exit the **Kivy app** on the Android device, the window does not close. It seems that the program crashes and the phone menu opens, but the program is still running.

I used these methods but did not get an answer:

```
os._exit()
sys.exit(0)
MDApp.stop()
MDApp.get_running_app().stop()
Window.close()
```

and added this fun to my MDApp:

```
def on_stop(self):
    return True
```

Comment: The problem was solved in: 
     https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8193

Comment: You can refer the Kivy documentation: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.close_settings